# How to produce space between words in css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button as follows,

```
    <button class="geomap-zoom-out" id="adpi-ann-comp-reset-button"">{{labelName}}</button>
```

laleName = "Switch to Full map"

I want the text in button button to be like,

```
                     Switch 
                       to
                    Full map
```

but when i add

```
     word-break: break-all;
```

It is producing space for all the words which is not desired.Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: Use <br/> to break a line. Switch <br/>to <br/>Full map

Comment: Try to use `word-break: break-word;` and set `min-width`

Comment: add `max-width` property to your button

Answer (score 0):

You can add the tag br and so no need of specific css
So it would be something like that :

```html
 <button class="geomap-zoom-out" id="adpi-ann-comp-reset-button">Switch<br>to<br>Full map</button>
```

Edit: In the code you shared, there is 2 " at the end of the id, you might want to remove one :)

Comment: I just made a change to my question,can you please look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br>` tag to `{lableName}`

```
<button class="geomap-zoom-out" id="adpi-ann-comp-reset-button"">{{labelName}}</button>
```

Your Label Name should be

```
<label>Switch<br>to<br>Full map</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, try this

```css
button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #f45e61;
  color: #f45e61;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.box{
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="box">Switch</br>to</br>Full map</button>
```